# Highlighted Text background and foreground - How to change?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Here is my scenario.  I like my color scheme.  I have a dark blue background with light grey text.  I have the Plain Text option in VS 2010 in Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors set to be a dark grey for the foreground and dark blue for the background:

[alt text http://www.elbalazo.net/post/vs_plaintext_color.jpg](http://www.elbalazo.net/post/vs_plaintext_color.jpg)

But I need to fix this major problem/annoyance which is when I highlight some text and then lost focus with my mouse it turns almost completely white!

[alt text http://www.elbalazo.net/post/WhiteBackgroundVS2.jpg](http://www.elbalazo.net/post/WhiteBackgroundVS2.jpg)

And worse, when I mouse over the little section lines of code on the left, the selection of the entire editor goes white with a light grey foreground for text:

[alt text http://www.elbalazo.net/post/WhiteBackgoundVS.jpg](http://www.elbalazo.net/post/WhiteBackgoundVS.jpg)

Not able to figure out where and how to fix this.  I don't see a way.  Note: I'm using R# 5.0+ so I don't know if that has anything to do with this color issue or what...maybe it's overriding some VS stuff or this is just a VS issue I don't know..probably just not looking in the right area under Fonts and colors...but a lot of the item foreground elements are read only.

UPDATED:

I think it might be (not sure) this one but I can't test it as the foreground is locked and not editable:

[alt text http://www.elbalazo.net/post/vs_brachmatching_color.jpg](http://www.elbalazo.net/post/vs_brachmatching_color.jpg)

Comment: Brace Matching is another setting, I belive. Try the `Collapsable Region` setting. I was able to replicate and fix just now using that one.

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure your first problem can be solved by setting the colors on the 'Highlighted Reference' option in the Fonts and Colors window. If ReSharper is override this setting I couldn't tell you. I don't have it installed on this machine. As for your second problem I have no idea.

If you get too irritated at trying to figure out the color options you could also try [Studio Styles](http://studiostyles.info/) for pre-made ones. I believe that is where I got the one I use currently.

Comment: I did not see that R# is overriding..but who knows.  I don't see in the R# menu anywhere that sets a color like this outside of VS's color settings.

Comment: Yea prefer to use my own styles but thanks.  Will check that out.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the setting you are looking for is "Inactive Selected Text". Found while trying to figure out why my selected search texts were not highlighted in an obvious manner.

Might be a year late... answering for future searches.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper is indeed overriding some of your settings, but those settings can be found in the same screen, towards the bottom of the listbox.

In `Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors`, scroll to the bottom of the 'Display Items:' listbox, and you should see a series of settings that start with `ReSharper`. For instance, the 'ReSharper Current Line Highlight` was causing me issues when I changed my theme to use a dark background.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks.  Well this particular issue isn't the R# Current Line Highlight...so still trying to figure this one out.

Comment: In fact -none- of the R# font and color options there is showing me a white background and very light gray foreground as you see happening in my examples there.  I remember checking this before so maybe it's just somewhere else...I just cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Try the `Collapsable Region` setting. I was able to replicate and fix just now using that one.

Comment: +1 this is exactly what caused the same problem in VS 2010 and R# 7.1. However, the "ReSharper Current Line Highlight" color was not being applied. The fix was to disable ReSharper's option for current line highlighting. I added an answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

The highlight for matching references is the "Highlighted Reference" background color (as Sean Copenhaver pointed out).

The highlight for the outlining region hover is "Collapsed Region" (as Brandon Satrom pointed out in his comment on the original question).  The foreground color is the color used in the outlining margin and the background color is the color used under the text.  You can also disable that highlight by disabling `Tools->Options->Environment->General->Enable rich client visual experience`, though that will disable other things (animations, gradients, etc.)

The brace matching rectangle is the highlight that appears when you insert or put the caret on a brace (e.g. ")", "]", "}").  It only lets you override the background color because you can't use it to change the foreground (text) color.

Comment: When I look at the Highlighted Reference foreground and background colors they are not what I'm seeing above.  I've looked at every property in that list so far and like I said the only one that I can see has that white background / light gray foreground is Collapsable Region..that's it!  that's the only one and I can't change it to try to see if that fixes it.  If you're saying it's these other ones, well the color schemes on them do not fit what I see at all when I look at them in Tools / fonts and colors...for the Text Editor template

Comment: If you want me to send the actual settings for vs 2010, specifically my color scheme that I created I can.  Note that I also have R# 5.0+ installed so you'd have to install that to replicate the exact environment I have.

Comment: If you think it's R# related, you should probably ping them for help (and/or make it very clear in the question title that this is a resharper question).  It's quite possible Resharper has placed a different item in that list that you can modify for the highlighted region, but I don't know what that is.  Also, are you saying that you can't change the Collapsible Region background/foreground?  Those are both editable in normal VS (and in Brandon's as well, from his comment), so you may want to ask resharper about that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem (much later) with VS 2010 and R# 7.1.

Disable the "Highlight current line" option in `ReSharper > Options > Environment > Editor`.

That option, when enabled, causes the VS 2010 color options for `Highlighted Reference` to not apply.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I had this problem without ReSharper and in my case tracked it down to the `Brace Matching (Rectangle)` color setting which looked nothing like what I was seeing in the editor but allowed me to fix the issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So this is weird but I was having the same problem and it simply went away when I went to Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors and changed the font size to 18.  I then went back in the same menu and changes it back to 10 (default) and the editor no longer highlights the collapsible regions white.  Strange behavior.